# LINQ to Entities many to many relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ and the Entity Framework and am having trouble coming up with a suitable query.

I have the following entities. I have included primary keys and some other relevant fields.

**Contact**
Int ContactId(PK),
String Name,
String EMailAddress

**Project**
Int ProjectId(PK)

**ProjectContact**
Int ProjectId(PK),
Int ContactId(PK),
Boolean IsPrimaryContact,
Boolean IsSecondaryContact

A project can have 1..n contacts, one of which is the primary contact for that project. Additionally if the project has more than one contact, one of the other contacts can be the secondary contact for that project.

A contact can be associated with many projects and may be the primary or secondary contact for several projects.

I need to generate an email for each group of projects that have a shared combination of primary and secondary contact. The idea is that the To field of the email contains the primary contact's email address, the CC field contains the secondary contact's email address (if there is a secondary contact) and the body of the email contains details of all the projects that have this combination of primary and secondary contacts.

I would like to populate a list containing objects with the following structure:

```
class EmailDetails
{
    public Contact PrimaryContact;
    public Contact SecondaryContact;
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects = new List<Project>();
}
```

So far I have this:

```
var QueryResults =
    from project in ProjectSet
        join primaryContact in ProjectContacts on project.ProjectId equals primaryContact.ProjectId where primaryContact.IsPrimary
        join secondaryContact in ProjectContacts on project.ProjectId equals secondaryContact.ProjectId where secondaryContact.IsSecondary
        select new {primaryContact, secondaryContact, project}
```

Where do I go from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[It's rarely correct to use `join` in L2E/L2S](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). Use associations/navigation properties instead.

Off the top of my head (may require some tweaking):

```
var QueryResults = from project in ProjectSet
                   let p = project.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsPrimary)
                   let s = project.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsSecondary)
                   group project by new { Primary = p, Secondary = s } into g
                   select new EmailDetails
                   {
                       PrimaryContact = g.Key.Primary,
                       SecondaryContact = g.Key.Secondary,
                       Projects = from proj in g
                                  select new ProjectDetails
                                  {
                                      Project = proj,
                                      Region = proj.Region,
                                      ProjectItems = proj.ProjectItems
                                  }
                   };
```

Comment: Thanks. This has got me much closer to what I need. Primary and secondary contacts, and projects have some associated entities I need access to. A contact has a navigation property to an Organisation object and a navigation property for a list of phone numbers. A project has a reference to a Region object and a list of ProjectItems. How can I efficiently get this data into memory? I'm usng EF3.5 so I believe lazy loading isn't an option? Sorry if I'm a bit off with the terminology, I'm still learning the ins and outs of this framework.

Comment: Easy way to do this in 3.5 (and 4) is to change `EmailDetails.Projects` to `IEnumerable<ProjectDetails>` (i.e., a view  or edit model, not an entity) and project onto that. I'll update the example.

Comment: Thanks. That works but is there a way to do this that doesn't require the creation of ProjectDetails and ContactDetails classes? I'd like to be able to access the region and ProjectItems via the navigation properties. It feels like it shouldn't be necessary to create new data structures just to be able to access related objects.

Comment: What makes you think you can't access these properties? Did you try what I suggested? Anonymous types work just as well if you don't like creating POCOs.